# Geolocation not working in Electron for windows store application (UAP) (Cordova-Electron app)

Tags: cordova, electron, geolocation, uap

Need to get this Cordova plugin working for Electron (or Browser) platforms:
[cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation).

The iOS, & Android implementation work great, but windows is deprecated because it uses IE11.  So we are porting our windows implementation to Electron platform.  The other platforms (iOS, android & windows) all utilize native (platform) code to get this done that we do not have access too in Electron or Browser platforms.

All we need is Latitude & Longitude!  We don't need maps, or any other data just those two numbers. **Therefore we do not need Google Maps API KEY**. (We do not need the google api key for the other platforms and we are not allowed to generate one for our existing product that already worked with out it). **NOTE**: google api key does solve our issue, but we are not allowed to use it for billing reasons.

In our web application we use the JavaScript `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);` prompting the user to allow location services and every thing works out great.

When we wrap (build) the existing web application in cordova/Electron this no longer works and we do not have native windows platform support.  We have also found Electron documentation that suggests you have to have a Google Maps API KEY.

Cordova/Electron documentation: [Cordova Electron](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/electron/) application to retrieve Latitude & Longitude.

I have started to look at the following paths, but we are struggling to get them to work correctly inside electron and not positive Windows Store will allow it.

- https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT (JavaScript specific to Windows platfrom)
- https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge (JavaScript that allows you to execute C# code)
- https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/blob/master/src/browser/BackgroundGeolocationMock.js#L165 (Only mocks out a default/Fake location)

Does anyone have an example of an Electron or Cordova app invoking a windows native dll or code?

#### Versions we are using:

- cordova: 10.0.0
- cordova-electron: 3.0.0
- electron: 14.0.0
- electron-builder: 22.11.7

Comment: What version of cordova-electron are you using? With WebView2 (fork of Chromium I believe)  on Windows, geo location should be built in like in the browser.

Comment: I have added the versions of cordova and electron we are using to the initial post.  Due to the fact we need to have a UWP Windows store app we are using Cordova/Electron.  Our version does not support WebView2.  I'm looking into what WebView2 has to offer and if there is a way I can port to WebView2.  Currently I'm not sure how to use WebVeiw2 to wrap our existing web app and generate a Windows mobile app we can deploy via windows store.

Answer (score 0):

What version of cordova-electron are you using? With WebView2 (fork of Chromium I believe)  on Windows, geo location should be built in like in the browser. I could be mistaken.
Have you tried (capital G)

```
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
```

You can also inspect the webview and check out what version it is building the app with, and check what methods are available.